# Managing releases on github

Tags: git, ant, github, release-management, git-branch

What's a good approach to handling software releases on github. My repo https://github.com/wheresrhys/jQuery-flickbook contains all the src and build files together with a built (minified) version of the javascript.

But I would also like it to, once I advance to the next version release, to include a e.g. jquery.flickbook-0.5.min.js file into a releases directory. To what degree can this be automated (using ant and git branches and tags), or is it something I will have to manually carry out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I'd do it (note: this makes the assumption that `master` is your "reference" branch):

- when you are ready to release a new version, create a branch `x.y-release` on `master` and check it out (`git checkout -b x.y-release master`);
- add your minified version, commit;
- create a tag `x.y` (`git tag x.y` -- you want to have a look at the manpage, you can create "tag objects" too);
- push the tag (not the branch) (`git push theremote --tags`, or even `git push theremote x.y`);
- when done, switch back to master (`git checkout master`);
- get rid of the release branch locally (`git branch -D x.y-release`) if you want to.

This means the minified version never makes its way into `master` but does end up in the tag, which means everything is there, as a tag is a refspec just as any branch is.

Comment: since posting the question I've come across this article http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/, which loooks good, but maybe it's overkill for a simple plugin with one developer working on it. Is it a good idea to set up a develop branch, and could your versioning approach be adapted to work with it?

Comment: Whether you want/need development branches is really up to you. It sure is useful if you want to test one or more features. In any case you will probably need a "reference" branch in which you'll merge your other branches, but in any case the trick I have given would work.

Comment: Yay - worked perfectly. I had a hell of a time getting it to work though as GIT wouldn't let me commit my empty releases folder in the master branch, but eventually I figured out I shodul put a .gitignore file in

Comment: I like this idea. Perhaps it could be used in my future for creating installer MSI files that also shouldn't need to be included in the actual VCS. ty!